# Csvhelper Ingore is removing only header column name but no the actual data

Tags: c#, .net-core, csvhelper

I loaded a csv file in my database with a DbId column not in the file.

I want to export it back to the original format.

My csvhelper mapping is in `MyCsvClass` with   `Map(m => m.DbId).Ignore();`

Header is fine, but output data is still showing values of DbId column:
https://dotnetfiddle.net/XP2Vvq

```
using CsvHelper.Configuration;
using System;
using System.IO;

namespace Test
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var record = new { DbId = 1, Data1 = "aaa", Data2 = "bbb" };

            using (var sw = new StreamWriter(@"c:/temp/testt.csv"))
            {
                using (var csvWriter = new CsvHelper.CsvWriter(sw))
                {
                    csvWriter.Configuration.RegisterClassMap<MyCsvClassMap>();
                    csvWriter.WriteHeader<MyCsvClass>();
                    csvWriter.NextRecord();
                    csvWriter.WriteRecord(record);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public class MyCsvClassMap : ClassMap<MyCsvClass>
    {
        public MyCsvClassMap()
        {
            AutoMap();
            Map(m => m.DbId).Ignore();
        }
    }

    public class MyCsvClass
    {
        public int DbId { get; set; }
        public string Data1 { get; set; }
        public string Data2 { get; set; }      
    }   
}
```

Output is

```
Data1, Data2
1, "aaa", "bbb"
```

when I expect

```
Data1, Data2
"aaa", "bbb"
```

Comment: You should read the documentation for `WriteHeader`...you are just removing-ignoring one of the headers column, but the data is still present in the `allRecords` `IEnumerable` and that's why `WriteRecords` is still writing the `DbId` field.

Comment: Using .CsvHelper 12.1.2, your code works fine (see example: https://dotnetfiddle.net/4baOjh). I suggest you update the CsvHelper library you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue with your code is that you create an instance of anonymous type

```
var record = new { DbId = 1, Data1 = "aaa", Data2 = "bbb" };
```

instead of

```
var record = new MyCsvClass { DbId = 1, Data1 = "aaa", Data2 = "bbb" };
```

The header is fine, because you pass the correct class to type parameter of the generic method.

```
csvWriter.WriteHeader<MyCsvClass>();
```

### Edit

To export DB entities to CSV you don't need any intermediate class. You can write entities directly to CSV and `ClassMap<T>` helps you control what values and how get serialized to CSV. If your entity class is `MyDbEntity`, then just register custom mapping `ClassMap<MyDbEntity>` where you auto-map all fields ignoring some fields as you did in your `MyCsvClassMap`.

Comment: As I said I want to use the automap feature. The workaround I am using is have a different CSV class for my input and my output. And use automapper to convert my database data to my output CSV class.

Comment: @sofsntp That requirement is not clearly stated in the question. It is just outlined in a comment under another answer. Anyway I still can't get my head around that. What prevents you from using `MyCsvClass` for exporting to CSV? Why are you forced to use anonymous type? Could you be more specific about your use case, so we can point you in the right direction? Make sure to put all the essential information to the question rather than a comment. It sounds like [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: When I record the original file in my database I am using several additional fields to store statistics and perform modifications. Then when I want to export, I need the original format without those additional columns meaning I have to map all the fields. I thought automap feature would word when writing, instead I am being forced to have two different CSV class and use automapper.

Comment: @sofsntp So is there any reason why you can't use `MyCsvClass` for exporting records? Mapping with ignored fields is specifically designed for this purpose.

Comment: yes true with automapper I can use just one MyCsvClass. Still the whole point of my question is why the automap feature of csvhelper is not working to convert my db entity to MyCsvClass

Comment: You registered `MyCsvClassMap` in your CSV writer, which is configured to map all properties of `MyCsvClass` except `DbId`. Then you write instances of anonymous type,but the writer is unable to use your mapping,because it expects instances of `MyCsvClass`. The result is the same as if you would use no mapping at all and the writer writes all properties of anonymous object to output. You mentioned some DB entity,but we can't see its structure in the question. You also mentioned [Automapper](https://automapper.org) which maps instances of one class to another. This is different from CSV mapping

Comment: ok understood now. What I needed to do is write a different ClassMap for my db entity, pass to the csv writers objects from the type of the entity

Comment: Yes, exactly, you don't need any intermediate class to write your DB entities to CSV. You can write them directly to CSV. Define mapping for your DB entity where you ignore properties that shoud not appear in CSV output.

Comment: Thank you. If you are ok to amend your answer to reflect that I'll accept it otherwise I am can write the answer myself.

Answer (score 0):

I think the `ClassMap` is not correctly configured. No idea why your example is working because it should not compile.

Can you modify the following line of code to register the `ClassMap` (`MyCsvClassMap` instead of `MyCsvClass`):

```
csvWriter.Configuration.RegisterClassMap<MyCsvClassMap>();
```

The rest of your example works fine.

Try the following console app:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var allRecords = new List<MyCsvClass>()
        {
            new MyCsvClass { DbId = "1", Data1 = "data1", Data2 = "data2"}
        };
        using (var sw = new StreamWriter("C:\\temp\\test.csv"))
        {
            using (var csvWriter = new CsvHelper.CsvWriter(sw))
            {
                csvWriter.Configuration.RegisterClassMap<MyCsvClassMap>();
                csvWriter.WriteHeader<MyCsvClass>();
                csvWriter.NextRecord();
                csvWriter.WriteRecords(allRecords);
            }
        }
    }

    public class MyCsvClassMap : ClassMap<MyCsvClass>
    {
        public MyCsvClassMap()
        {
            AutoMap();
            Map(m => m.DbId).Ignore();
        }
    }

    public class MyCsvClass
    {
        public string DbId { get; set; }
        public string Data1 { get; set; }
        public string Data2 { get; set; }
    }
}
```

If this is working there is maybe some other code which causes this behavior.

Comment: sorry, would have been better to have this as a comment. You're right, it's a typo. I edited the question, but it's not solving the issue

Comment: Which version of .net core and CsvHelper are you using? I tried your example, the DbId is not written.

Comment: csvhelper 12.1.2 and .net core 2.2

Comment: Can you try the console app i added to my comment?

Comment: @sofsntp, just saw your comment here. Weirdly, my dotnetfiddle example using your code and CsvHelper 12.1.2 works just fine... (https://dotnetfiddle.net/4baOjh). I suspect something else is going on in your code, and the code pieces in your question are not causing the problem just by themselves...

Comment: I updated a full test. Not checked yours yet but I am pretty sure that you pass objects of same class MyCsvClass while I want to rely on automap feature